# Call php class in anothet file in another class

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

I have slight problem in my code. I'm supposed to call a function in another function in my php script. However the two function are in different scripts. I'm trying to run the scripts and they're just throwing errors. Here's a sample of how I'm writing my scripts. The first script is confirmLib.php

```
<?php
class confirmClass{
function confirm()
{
return true;
}

}?>
```

The second is usersLib.php

```
 <?php
require("confirmLib.php");
class user
{

var $confirmed= null;
}


public addUser(){
$comfirmUser = new confirmClass();
$confirmed = $comfirmUser->confirm()
}

addUser();
?>
```

Comment: And it didn't occur to you to actually paste the errors too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got plenty of basic errors, why not just bugfix?

```
 <?php
require("confirmLib.php");
class user
{

var $confirmed= null;
}
```

This `}` shouldn't be there. it closes the class.

```
public addUser(){
```

You'r missing the keyword "function"

```
$comfirmUser = new confirmClass();
$confirmed = $comfirmUser->confirm()
```

You're missing a `;`

```
}

addUser();
```

What is this doing here? You should close your class here, and then add a `new user` call and a `user->addUser()` call too.

Comment: Wouldn't make sense to call `addUser` on a `user` object, unless you're nesting users...

Comment: Maybe, but the complete design is a bit shaky. You could see the "adduser" as a standalone function (then the 'public' should be removed, and some `}` should go higher. But then you might also wonder what sort of class "confirm" is, and if you wouldn't want a confirm member in a user class, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you wrote `public addUser()` while PHP always forces you to use the keyword `function` as well.

```
public function addUser(){
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `addUser` method do this:

```
public addUser() 
{
    $confirmUsers = new confirmClass();
    $user = new user();
    $user->confirmed = $confirmUsers->confirm();
}
```